# Converting X and Y to lat/long using UTM WGS-1984 48N projection system

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system

I am using street directory API and it is using the UTM WGS-1984 48N projection system. I only need to convert static values! I am mostly using JavaScript but at the moment I'm alright with any solutions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenLayers coordinates conversion as below, but you need to add reference to OpenLayers script:

```
 <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>

        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:32648");   //refers to epsg projection 32648 - wgs 84 / utm zone 48n
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // to  wgs 84 
        var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.41,52.52).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

    </script>
```

source:
[Example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example)

Comment: The source data is in UTM zone 48N, and target should be in degrees. So this attempt does not deliver the needed values.

Comment: In this case, if as @J. Doe don't mind using any solution, there is a library in python to convert from UTM to lon & lat.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm

Comment: http://proj4js.org/ should do almost the same in javascript. But I have no experience with it.

Comment: Source: **EPSG:32648** refers to epsg projection 32648 - wgs 84 / utm zone 48n.    
Target: **EPSG:4326** refers to epsg projection  wgs 84

Answer (score 0):

you can use this type of function as a parameter sending him a point and will return you to become longitude and latitude

```
convertPointGeoToGrades:function(point){
                console.log("pointMercator",point);
            var coordLatLong = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(point);
            console.log("coordLatLong",coordLatLong);
            var coordLatGrad = null;
            var coordLatMin = null;
            var coordLatSeg = null;
            var coordLongGrad = null;
            var coordLongMin = null;
            var coordLongSeg = null;
            // got dashes?
            //if ((coordLatLong.x.toString().substr(0,1) != "-")||(coordLatLong.y.toString().substr(0,1) != "-")) {
            //    alert("Selecciona una ubicacion dentro de Bolivia");
            //    this.clearAll();
            //}
            //else {
            // degrees = degrees
            coordLatGrad = coordLatLong.x.toString().split(".");
            dojo.byId("coordLatGrad").value = coordLatGrad[0];

            coordLongGrad = coordLatLong.y.toString().split(".");
            dojo.byId("coordLongGrad").value = coordLongGrad[0];

            // * 60 = mins
            var ddLatRemainder = ("0." + coordLatGrad[1]) * 60;
            coordLatMin = ddLatRemainder.toString().split(".");
            dojo.byId("coordLatMin").value = coordLatMin[0];

            var ddLongRemainder = ("0." + coordLongGrad[1]) * 60;
            coordLongMin = ddLongRemainder.toString().split(".");
            dojo.byId("coordLongMin").value = coordLongMin[0];

            // * 60 again = secs
            var ddLatMinRemainder = ("0." + coordLatMin[1]) * 60;
            dojo.byId("coordLatSeg").value = (ddLatMinRemainder).toFixed(4);

            var ddLongMinRemainder = ("0." + coordLongMin[1]) * 60;
            dojo.byId("coordLongSeg").value = (ddLongMinRemainder).toFixed(4);
            //}
        }
```

Comment: OP can't use the webMercatorUtils because the data is in UTM so how is this helpful?